# Multiple threads in windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, windows-services, thread-safety

I have windows project and one form which have timer for each 5 seconds.

It calls and processes methods from request named table time wise and condition wise.

But I have some methods types which takes too much time to respond and want those methods in separate thread. So that I can run those both request types in separate threads and syncs.

How can I do separate those both using thread -- multi async threads?

Comment: You have a "windows service" with "one form"? Confused.

Comment: Yes, I have windows project and having one form which is running in background as one service (myproject.exe).

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you look at the .NET 4.0 `Task` class. Firing full threads every time might be overkill. Tasks, together with timers use the underlying thread pool to execute work in parallel.

Using a `Task` is as simple as:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
       () => 
       {
           // task code here
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(B));
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
    }

    static void A()
    {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine('A');
    }

    static void B()
    {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine('B');
    }
}
```

[Threading Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread)

Comment: So It means, my service will call method A and B async .. if A waits for 10 minutes then B will async call and execute its code right?

Comment: There are actually three threads in this example - the two `Thread` objects and the main UI thread.  The downside to this approach is that the main UI thread is locked until the two `Thread` objects finish their work.

Comment: Thanks.. I wanted to do that because I have lots of request and its respective methods in service to execute but some request methods takes too much time and lots of process in it so want those in separate thread so that other small request methods can easily get in.