# Timed Windows Service - What If Custom Processes Take Longer Than The Timer Interval?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have Windows Service that is pulling in around 100 items of data every 30 seconds (based on a Timer) from a jSON feed.

At the moment, the service is working well. But my only concern is on the unlikely event that it takes longer than the 30 second interval for the incoming data to be processed and sent to a database.

Could anyone advise on the best way way to ensure that the data can be processed without causing any hold up. Due to the data provided by the jSON feed is live and current, I need to be sure that I do not miss an incoming request.

In addition, am I going down the right approach by creating a Windows Service that runs on a regular interval rather than using Scheduled Task?

### Update

After some research, I was thinking of disabling the timer within the Timer_Elapsed event:

```
void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;

    //Carry out custom processes

   timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

So my custom processes should have enough time to complete before the timer starts again.

Would something like this be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

You should dedicate a seperate thread for reading the data from the JSON feed. The processing of the feed and storage to database should take place in another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Having separate threads seems like a good option. I haven't built a multiple threaded service before and is this something that would work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11985369/1300806? So each thread will perform some function and after each interval, have a delay to allow the data processing to finish?